# Regex validate last name issues

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a form before it is inserted into the db.
First name, last name and email address. Email address works fine. It is the last name I am having a problem with, which also means I am having a problem with the first name.

The first and last name allow any characters at the moment, including numbers and symbols. where have I gone wrong?

```
  if (preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,45}$/i', $_POST['lname'])) {
    $c_lname = escape_data($_POST['lname'], $dbc);
} else {
    $c_lnameError = ("Please enter your last name!");
}
```

This is my validation, I am trying to use Regex to insist the value is between 2 to 45 characters and only contains a combination of upper and lower case letters, a space, a period, an apostrophe and a hyphen.
Any help would be much appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php
 $c_fnameError = $c_lnameError = $c_emailError = $c_phoneError = "";

if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
$c_fname = $_POST['fname'];
$c_lname = $_POST['lname'];
$c_email = $_POST['email'];
$c_phone = $_POST['phone'];   
//validate laste name
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,45}$/i', $_POST['lname'])) {
    $c_lname = escape_data($_POST['lname'], $dbc);
} else {
    $c_lnameError = ("Please enter your last name!");
}
// validate email
if (!filter_var($c_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {       
        } else {
           $c_emailError = ("<b> Email is not a valid email address</b>");
        }      
$insert_det = "INSERT INTO Cus_acc_details(CUS_Fname,CUS_Lname,Cus_Email,CUS_Phone) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE
    Cus_acc_details.CUS_Fname = '$c_fname',
    Cus_acc_details.Cus_Lname = '$c_lname',
    Cus_acc_details.Cus_Email = '$c_email',
    Cus_acc_details.CUS_Phone = '$c_phone'";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_det);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $c_fname, $c_lname, $c_email, $c_phone);
/* execute query */
$r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if ($r) {
    echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<b>Oops! we have an issu </b>";
}
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <!--                    <div id="first">-->
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" required> 
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?>"  required>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Cus_Email']; ?>" required>
    <!-- Onclick only accept numbers between 0-9-->
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone']; ?>"  onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required>
    <!-- id = phone error messge-->
    <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">Oops! I can only accept numbers</span>
    <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: You should not rely on latin characters only, unless you want to exclude all users with any foreign characters in their names. For example, my surname "Groß" would not pass the test, nor would any Spanish name including "ñ", Swedish names with "ø" etc. etc. So you should rather use a blacklist (numbers, interpunctation, ...) instead of a whitelist.

Comment: What function is `escape_data`? It is not a built in php function and if you are preparing/binding your SQL, escaping is not needed. Your regex looks fine for the most part: https://regex101.com/r/zK2iV8/1 (I just added parenthesis around it and added flags to show all the matches). The biggest issues I can see are that it allows for multiple spaces/symbols and leading/trailing symbols.

Comment: I did just notice looking over the code that you set a few variables if there was an error, but still just insert into the database anyways. You should at least check if there was an error and display the message instead of inserting. Currently you just set a variable. That won't stop any code below from running by itself. I personally have always preferred appending errors to an array because it makes it easier to just check `if(empty($errors)){ /*all good, do something*/} else { /*show errors*/ }`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thank me. i will look into your suggestions